# How to change jquery jtable edit modal form input box fields by textarea fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I have been working on jQuery jtable API's and everything works fine but when I click the edit button icon the edit modal form will pop up and the fields inside the modal form is all input boxes but my content inside jtable is a paragraph and quite difficult to edit in that smaller text box. So anybody can help me how to change the default edit modal form input box by text area that any length of text can seen and edited easily in that text area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the api reference for [Type](http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference/FieldOptions#fopt-type). You have to just add type option for field.
For example-

```
About: {
    title: 'About this person',
    type: 'textarea'
},
```

For example is already given [here](http://www.jtable.org/Demo/PagingAndSorting).